# What is proofOfWorkLimit?

Tags: bitcoinj, proof-of-work, bitcoin-wallet-app

Look at the code below from android bitcoin wallet:

```
proofOfWorkLimit = Utils.decodeCompactBits(0x1d00ffffL);
```

And look at the code from bitcoin qt wallet:

```
static CBigNum bnProofOfWorkLimit(~uint256(0) >> 32);
```

I assume that in second case ProofOfWorkLimit is 32 "0" and 224 "1" (000000...000111111111....11111111)?

So I don't have an idea how to get first case "0x1d00ffffL" from second case?
In binary "0x1d00ffffL" is 11101000000001111111111111111.

P.S. I have looked in uint256.h. It wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first byte, 1D, is the length. The next three bytes are the high bytes of the hash. So we have `00ffff`, then we add `ff` bytes onto the end to get to 29 bytes. Then we're done.

We wind up with 3 bytes of leading zeroes because 32-29 is 3. And we get one byte of zeroes from the second byte of the compact bits. So the final result is 00,00,00,00,ff,ff,ff...

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am still confused. Can your answer how to get "first case" from "static CBigNum bnProofOfWorkLimit(~uint256(0) >> 27);" ?

Comment: ~0 means all bits set. `>> 32` means to shift the bits left by 32 bits, shifting in zeroes in their place.

Comment: Thanks again. Sorry for insistence but can you answer what exactly should I put here "Utils.decodeCompactBits(0x1d00ffffL);" in case "~uint256(0) >> 27" ?

Comment: You want 27 zero bits. That's 3 bytes of all zero bits, followed by 3 more zero bits. `00011111` is `1F`. Since the whole thing is 32 bytes, and we need 3 zero bytes, the length of the non-zero segment is 29 bytes, which in hex is 1D. So unless I made a mistake, I get `0x1D1FFFFF`.